# How to Install Maven in AWS CodeBuild Standard Linux 2.0 (Ubuntu 18.0)

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to build my project using **AWS** **Codebuild**. Below is my **buildspce.yml**. My source code is in s3 bucket and file type is zip.

```
 version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
       java: openjdk8
    commands:
        - apt-get update -y
        - apt-get install -y maven
  pre_build:
    commands:
       - java -version
       - mvn -version 
      # - command
  build:
    commands:
       - echo Entered the build phase...
       - echo Build started on `date`
       - mvn package -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
      # - command
    finally:
      - echo This always runs even if the install command fails
  #post_build:
    #commands:
      # - command
      # - command
#reports:
  #report-name-or-arn:
    #files:
      # - location
      # - location
    #base-directory: location
    #discard-paths: yes
    #file-format: JunitXml | CucumberJson
#artifacts:
  #files:
    # - location
    # - location
  #name: $(date +%Y-%m-%d)
  #discard-paths: yes
  #base-directory: location
#cache:
  #paths:
    # - paths
```

I got `COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: apt-get install -y maven. Reason: exit status 100` error in INSTALL phase. Even If I remove maven from Install phase and only add `mvn package` then also got error with `exit code 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Maven is already installed in `java: openjdk8` as can be confirmed here [1].

Did a quick test:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: openjdk8

  build:
    commands:
      - mvn -v
```

Build Logs:

```
[Container] 2020/01/23 10:51:01 Running command mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T19:00:29Z)
Maven home: /opt/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_222, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.14.152-98.182.amzn1.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

[1] https://github.com/aws/aws-codebuild-docker-images/blob/master/ubuntu/standard/2.0/Dockerfile